# AudioKit: Why is the SoundpipeAudioKit PitchTap class failing to build?

Tags: audiokit

Hello I am new to the world of AudioKit and Swift in general.

I am trying to use the SoundpipeAudioKit project on my project because I want to add a AmplitudeEnvelope. I am building a iOS AUv3 instrument with this project.

The problem is that after I add the package my build fails.
I am adding via the Xcode add package tool.

This is the error message I am getting:

```
SoundpipeAudioKit/Sources/SoundpipeAudioKit/PitchTap.swift:42:80 Extra argument 'callbackQueue' in call
```

Which is pointing to here:

```
   /// Initialize the pitch tap
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - input: Node to analyze
    ///   - bufferSize: Size of buffer to analyze
    ///   - handler: Callback to call on each analysis pass
    public init(_ input: Node, bufferSize: UInt32 = 4096, handler: @escaping Handler) {
        self.handler = handler
        super.init(input, bufferSize: bufferSize, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

All I did was add the SoundpipeAudioKit via the add package feature of Xcode. I then tried to build my project, which failed, and this error keeps coming up. If I remove the library my project builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:

https://github.com/AudioKit/SoundpipeAudioKit/issues/32

Seems like there is an issue with the latest version of the library pointing to the wrong version of AudioKit. The current solution is to point to a different version of the library.